# Port forward from lan router (global way)

Tags: python, network-programming, ip, portforwarding

Is there any global way to manage port forward (via telnet from example) for any type of router?

I want to do this with python (if it's possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any global way to manage port forward (via telnet from example) for any type of router?

No, unfortunately not. There are web interfaces, consoles (telnet or SSH), APIs, and they're all at least vendor-specific. Some consumer-grade devices support UPnP, which can be used for port forwarding, but leaving UPnP active is most often a security problem.

There are quite a few python libraries for that, so you might want to check them out.